# VC++ 6.0 application crashing inside CString::Format when %d is given

Tags: crash, format, visual-c++-6, cstring

A VC++ 6.0 application is crashing when doing a CString::Format operation with %d format specifier. This does not occur always but occurs when the application memory grows upto 100MB or more.
ALso sometimes same crash observed when a CString copy is done.
The call stack would look like this

mfc42u!CFixedAlloc::Alloc+82

mfc42u!CString::AllocBuffer+3f
     00000038
     00000038
     005b5b64

mfc42u!CString::AllocBeforeWrite+31
     00000038
     0a5bfdbc
     005b5b64

mfc42u!CString::AssignCopy+13
     00000038
     057cb83f
     0a5bfe90

mfc42u!CString::operator=+4b

and this throws an access violation exception.

Comment: Code is pretty straight forward. Either it would be 
LPCTSTR lpctstrMsg;
CString str = lpctstrsMsg;

or for the format one it would be 
str.Format(_T("%d"), n);
where n is an integer.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're crashing while allocating memory, then it may be due to heap corruption.  Run your application under [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480483.aspx) with the Heaps test enabled.  This enable you to see various issues in your code like double frees, heap ovveruns/underruns and so on.

Comment: i understand that but my concern is it crashes in the same location repeatedly but only after the application runs upto a memory of 100MB or more. but why would heap corruption also affect string.format

Comment: Format may need to allocate memory in order to grow the internal buffer.

Comment: yeah even i thought of that but is there a case when this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't it, but I recently came across [a known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225099) with realloc corrupting the small block heap under VS6. If you have a realloc (or use of something like vector that uses realloc) elsewhere in your code, it could cause what you are seeing.

The fix for the issue is to either hack realloc.c, write your own realloc function, or do a "_set_sbh_threshold(0)" in your code to disable that obsolete small block heap.

Comment: you should also verify you have service pack 6 installed